# Detect click inside an svg javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, select

```
<div id="anim">
    <svg>
        <defs><clipPath id="__lottie_element_2"></defs>
        <g>
            <g class="aaaaa"></g>
            <g id="bbbbb"></g>
            <g id="ccccc"></g>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Detect when I click on class="aaaa" inside id="anim" and throw an alert. alert("you have pressed class" aaaa)
Detect when I click on id="bbbbb" inside id="anim" and throw an alert. alert("you have pressed id" bbbbb)

thank you

```
    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    
    
    let element = document.querySelector("div.anim > svg > g > g").getAttribute("id");

    element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("You clicked");
    

      });
```

Comment: Why are you calling `.getAttribute("id")`?

Comment: you've not drawn any shapes or text to click on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [closest() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to find the parent `<g>` that was clicked. The `<g>` does not itself take any click events, so you rely on the content of the `<g>`.

And you just need one event listener for the entire thing. e.target is the element that was clicked (depending on how you use [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) if that is something you can use in your case).

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  let element = document.querySelector("div#anim");

  element.addEventListener("click", e => {
    let gclicked = e.target.closest('g');
    alert(`You have pressed class ${gclicked.getAttribute('class')}`);
  });
})
```

```html
<div id="anim">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 30 10" width="300">
    <g class="aaaaa">
      <circle r="5" cx="5" cy="5" fill="red"/>
    </g>
    <g class="bbbbb">
      <circle r="5" cx="15" cy="5" fill="blue"/>
    </g>
    <g class="ccccc">
      <circle r="5" cx="25" cy="5" fill="orange"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I need it to go in (to the child <g> node) like the example because it's exported from After Effects and I can't change it.

Comment: I had to add let gclicked = e.target.closest('div#anim > svg > g > g'); thank you

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  // `div.anim` means div with class anim
  // why would you use `getAttribute` here?
  let element = document.querySelector("div#anim > svg > g > g");

  element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("You clicked");
  });
})
```

```html
<div id="anim">
  <svg>
        <!-- you forgot to close `<clipPath>` -->
        <defs><clipPath id="__lottie_element_2"></clipPath></defs>
        <g>
            <g class="aaaaa"></g>
            <g id="bbbbb"></g>
            <g id="ccccc"></g>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I know which one has clicked? alert aaaa or bbbb or cccc :-(